# Rank the dates in a table for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

I need to find the last three distinct loaddates for each month in various tables for reporting purposes. Example: If I have data from 2021 February to today: I need the three loaddates of Feb 2021, March 2021 and so on till. Dec 2022

So far, I'm able to create the below query in SQL Server which gives me the result for a particular month that I pass in the where condition.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY loaddate desc) AS myrank, loaddate
    FROM <tablename>
    where year(loaddate) = 2022 and month(loaddate) = 6
    group by loaddate
```

It gives me:

```
myrank  loaddate
1       2022-08-29 00:00:00.000
2       2022-08-25 00:00:00.000
3       2022-08-18 00:00:00.000
4       2022-08-17 00:00:00.000
5       2022-08-11 00:00:00.000
```

From this I can easily select the top three dates with the below query:

```
SELECT myrank, loaddate
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY loaddate desc) AS myrank, loaddate
    FROM <tablename>
    where year(loaddate) = 2022 and month(loaddate) = 6
    group by loaddate
) as daterank
WHERE daterank.myrank <= 3
```

which outputs:

```
rank    loaddate
1       2022-08-29 00:00:00.000
2       2022-08-25 00:00:00.000
3       2022-08-18 00:00:00.000
```

But this is only for one month. I'm manually passing the month number in the where condition. How to make this ranking query give me the the last 3 distinct loaddates for each month of data that exists in the table?

And also, how to do I run such a generic query on list of 400+ tables instead of changing the tablename manually for each table in the list?

Comment: "how to do I run such a generic query on list of 400+" SQL is a static language and is intended to be. However it you need to run it against dynamic table use dynamic SQL... its a big topic, I suggest you research it.

Comment: And please only ask a single question per question. So ask your dynamic SQL question separately as its a totally different, and unrelated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just add the `PARTITION BY` clause to `ROW_NUMBER()` and partition by month (and year since your data might cross a year boundary).

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEPART(year, loaddate), DATEPART(month, loaddate) ORDER BY loaddate desc) AS myrank
    FROM #MyTable
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE myrank <= 3
ORDER BY loaddate;
```

Note: The CTE is doing the same thing as your sub-query - don't let that confuse you - I just prefer it for neatness.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request I think this would help you:

```
SELECT myrank, loaddate, monthofyear
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY month(loaddate) ORDER BY loaddate DESC) AS myrank
        , loaddate, month(loaddate) as monthofyear
    FROM Db15.dbo.mytable
    GROUP BY loaddate
) AS daterank
WHERE daterank.myrank <= 3
```